# How to modify SOAP headers on every method call

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, request-headers

I've got a wrapper for a WCF service that has a number of methods.  On every method, I'm to insert a `sessionId` and a `deviceId` for authentication.  These values change on instantiation and you're supposed to dispose of them after you're done.

I'm aware that you can do this to modify the headers on a call:

```
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope((IClientChannel)this.client.InnerChannel))
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("SessionId", this.sessionId);
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.Headers.Add("DeviceKey", this.deviceKey.ToString());
    return this.client.MyMethod("call");
}
```

I don't want to paste this 20 times.  Is there a way to do this cleanly?  I can probably make use of `Reflection` and invoke.  But my methods do not have uniform values and arguments.

```
public class Service {
    private string sessionId; //needed for auth
    private string deviceId; // needed for auth
    public Service (string userName, string password) {}

    public string[] GetList() {}
    public Foo[] GetSomethingElse(Bar arg) {}
    public List<Baz> GetTheThing(Fez org) {}
    // etc... x 20
}
```

Comment: This is a smidge dated, but it could give you some ideas: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility/

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is [IClientMessageInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) and its method [BeforeSendRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.beforesendrequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

From here you could do something like this

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty prop;
    if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name))
    {
         prop = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
    }
    else
    {
         prop = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
         request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, prop);
    }

    prop.Headers.Add("SessionId", this.sessionId);
    prop.Headers.Add("DeviceKey", this.deviceKey.ToString());

}
```

Before sending each message (as method name implies) it will modify headers accordingly.

Ogh, aand here's the link how you can register class implementing this interface [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx)